Who are the wives of Rishi Durvasa?
This particular chapter from the Shiva Puran on Shiva's dalliance with Parvati mentions something interesting:


The sage Durvāsas separated Indra in copulation with Rambhā and the sage got separation from his wife as a result thereof.
He took another woman as his wife and thus put an end to the pangs of separation lasting for a thousand years of the gods.


From this statement made by Lord Vishnu it appears that Durvasa rishi had two wives one of whom he was separated from. Wikipedia mentions Durvasa cursing his own wife Kandali to turn into dust and mentions the Brahma-vaivarta Puran as a reference. If that's correct, she may be considered the first wife from whom he was separated through his own anger but I would like to know more about her.
Are the stories of Durvasa rishi's two wives available in any Purans and if so can someone share the available references?

Ṛṣi Durvāsā had a wife named Kandalī, daughter of Ṛṣi Aurva. Later, his wife was Ekanāṁśa (i.e. Yogamāyā), sister of Kṛṣṇa and daughter of Nanda & Yaśodā. Check Brahmavaivarta Purāṇa (4.24) and (4.7).

But before having vivāha with Kandalī, Durvāsā was a brahmacārī only

@Bingming can you share the details with the reference as an answer? Ekanamsa Devi is equated with Vindhya Vasini, who killed Shumbh and Nishumbh am surprised that her marriage to Durvasa is not mentioned anywhere else.

I have already shared the reference here with the adhyāya and khaṇḍa number which you can easily check if you want detail, and I have no intention of giving it as an answer to the post (it's a straigtforward answer). In Brahmavaivarta Purāṇa, Ekanaṁśā is used as a name for Yaśodā and Nanda's daughter who is swapped with Kṛṣṇa by Vasudeva. You may check the above given reference, if there's doubt regarding this.
